# Pycharm:Getting UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycharm

My code when I run on terminal runs without error but when running on pycharm is producing following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Also when run on pycharm's terminal ,I am getting following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/swastik/Downloads/Hindi_SentiWordNet/abhi.py", line 19, 
in <module>
 di.write(str(i))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2- 
5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The same code is running without any error on my MAC OS's terminal and when run on ubuntu 16.04 ,it runs fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
with open('annot.txt',encoding='utf-8') as h:
    an = h.readlines()
with open('MOD_HN_POS.txt',encoding='utf-8') as n:
    non = n.readlines()
anno = []
for i in an:
   anno.append(i.strip())
diff = {}
for i in non:
   if i.strip() not in anno:
      diff[i] = 0
di = open('diffpos.txt', 'w')
for i in diff.items():
   di.write(str(i))
di.close()
```

How to correct it in pycharm?

Comment: Your `coding` comment is doing nothing. That's needed only if the *source code* contains non-ASCII characters, it does not fix encoding issues when reading&writing files. In your case it seems **external files** contain such characters and you are reading them without specifying the correct encoding. Specify `encoding=` when you read `diffneg.txt`. Note that that file is not utf-8, so you'll have to check which encoding it is

Comment: That last error message is a bit odd. Is "diffpos.txt" a data file, or is it a Python script?

Comment: BTW, if you want to do a diff on the bytes of those files you should open them in binary mode.

Comment: @PM2Ring ,it is a data file

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta ,I checked and it is UTF-8 `annot.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Mark Then try to add `open(.., encoding='utf-8')` and see if this fixed the problems. If it doesn't then the file is not utf-8. BTW: the errors you have posted mention `diffpos.txt` but your code contains `diffneg.txt`. Be aware that by lieing in your question you are making it harder for us to help you. You should provide the real code you are using and when posting tracebacks you should post the *full* traceback, not just the last line like you have shown.

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't fix the problem ,Now I am getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-5: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta,I'll edit the details